# Rotation Path Not Shown in Graph Editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I created a couple of LocRot keyframes but the rotation path and keyframes aren't shown in the graph editor (no, they aren't hidden).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the object that you keyframed, selected. By default the graph editor only shows keyframs from the selected object(s).

Or if you need to work on it with the object deselected, you can show all object's keyframes in the graph editor by disabling the *Show Only Selected* as part of the *View controls* in the header.
[image: Show Only Selected]

Comment: Also it worth noting that *F-Curve* mode should be selected, not *Drivers* (it is by default though).